# Query fails with multiple conditions

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

I've a database that i have implemented a searchView to search through its data
using this query:

the selection:

```
//rooms.name = ? OR rooms.name LIKE ? OR rooms.name LIKE ? OR rooms.name LIKE ?
    private static final String roomsWithSectorsByNameSelection =
        DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                "." + DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " = ? OR " +
                DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                "." + DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ? OR " +
                DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                "." + DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ? OR " +
                DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                "." + DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?";
```

the table:

```
roomsWithSectorsByNameQueryBuilder.setTables(
            DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " +
                    DeltaContract.SectorsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    " ON " + DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.COLUMN_SECTOR_ID + " = " +
                    DeltaContract.SectorsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + DeltaContract.SectorsEntry._ID);
```

and the query:

```
    private Cursor getRoomsWithSectorsByName(Uri uri, String[] projection, String sortOrder) {

    String name = DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.getNameFromRoomsUri(uri);

    return roomsWithSectorsByNameQueryBuilder.query(deltaDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            projection,
            roomsWithSectorsByNameSelection,
            new String[]{name, (name + "%"), ("%" + name + "%"), ("%" + name)},
            DeltaContract.SectorsEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + DeltaContract.SectorsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
            null,
            sortOrder
    );
}
```

for most of searches i try it works splendidly but for certain rows it doesn't work even if i type the entire word

**BUT**

if i change the selection to this:

```
//rooms.name = ?
private static final String roomsWithSectorsByNameSelection =
    DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
            "." + DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " = ?";
```

and the query to this:

```
private Cursor getRoomsWithSectorsByName(Uri uri, String[] projection, String sortOrder) {

String name = DeltaContract.RoomsEntry.getNameFromRoomsUri(uri);

return roomsWithSectorsByNameQueryBuilder.query(deltaDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
        projection,
        roomsWithSectorsByNameSelection,
        new String[]{name},
        DeltaContract.SectorsEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + DeltaContract.SectorsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
        null,
        sortOrder
);
```

}

removing all the likes, it works fine,

it should be noted that if i search the table using different columns for the rows the first query fails to find, it works and the rows are returned

it should also be noted that the data in the rows are stored in the Arabic language

so any help please? thank you

**EDIT**

for example:
in the first state using the query with all the likes, when i search for "رئيس مجلس الإدارة" which is shown here in the first row:

(image number one)

searching by name it only gets similar rows:

(image number two)

but when i search by phone number it finds it:

(image number three)

even if i write the phone number in arabic:

(image number four)

here are the images (put them in one link due to limitations caused by low reputation)

[the images](http://pho.to/AhQzx)

now when i change the query and remove all the likes it just finds it:

[using the query with no likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqfof.jpg)

it should also be noted that the problem isn't limited to this row, it did occur with other rows too following the same behavior

Comment: Show some example data.

Comment: [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125)

Comment: @CL.
[here are the tables in my database](http://pho.to/AhR9z)

couldn't do it in that site cause Arabic rtl alignment messed it up

Comment: this is the table resulted from the join which is used for the search [here](http://imgur.com/8OXaLN4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it,

the problem occurred because of the group by parameter at the query,
i have no clue why it caused the problem but removing it just solved it.